# Is there a way to edit a column in an attribute table at once within an Arc geodatabase when there is subtype and coded domain?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, domains, subtype

In a regular shapefile with no coded properties, I can use 'Field Calculator' on my selected features to change all attribute rows at once. However with subtypes and coded domains there are drop-downs.

Is there a script I can run or similar to do this batch at once. There are 500+ records I need to change, and that would be very tedious work.

Answer (score 1):

The Field Calculator will work on fields with Domains and Subtypes.  You need to enter the coded value into your field calculator rather than the Domain Description, but other than that it'll work the same way it does for any other field.

If you have a domain like:

```
1 | Monday
2 | Wednesday
3 | Friday
```

[image]

and want to populate your selected records with Wednesday, you'd open your Field Calculator on the specific field, and just enter a `2` as the value you want to calculate.  For `Monday` enter `1` and `Friday` enter `3`

[image]

[image]